# Out of the Box Python Database Connector

Tags: python, pandas, database, connection

I have been trying to find an out-of-the-box python database connector that comes pre-packaged with python 3.x (currently running 3.6.10). I am trying to avoid installing a third party module like cx_Oracle, pyodbc, etc. Reason being, if I have to go that route, I would have to install the third party module across multiple computers for my script to run among my organization.

Purpose, I am executing multiple sql's using pandas and using the resultant dataframe throughout my script.

Currently, I have (which works for now):

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(~my connection parameters)
db = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password, dsn=dsn)

sql = '''select * from mytable'''

df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=db)
```

So basically, I need to pass a database connection (db) into the pandas sql executor and I'd like to use something that comes pre-packaged with my python version, if possible.

Comment: Installing cx_Oracle and Instant Client make most technical sense for Pandas.  You already have to install some things - Python and pandas.  Installing cx_Oracle is trivial (via pip), and you can script the download and installation of Instant Client.

Comment: @Christopher Jones basic steps to install additional packages on a standalone desktop install of python... trivial, yes. When working in a large enterprise installation of python that is tightly controlled, not so trivial. So, working with something pre-packaged would be the easier solution in my case.